# Access warns that there is an operator error in the case clause in the query

Tags: ms-access

Access warns that there is an operator error in the case clause in the query
(line 3)
can't find what is wrong

```
SELECT x, y, z
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT x,y,
CASE WHEN Forms![g]![d] !=0  THEN z  ELSE Forms![g]![d] END) AS Z
...;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually 2 separate problems with that line.

1. Access has no `CASE WHEN` statements, and uses either the `IIF` function or `SWITCH` function instead
2. `!=` is not a valid operator in Access. The not equals operator is `<>`.

Corrected:

```
IIF(Forms![g]![d] <> 0, z, Forms![g]![d]) AS EXP
```